# Dictionary. Create a dictionary that maps the first n counting numbers to their squares

Tags: python

```
for n in raage(n):
    if n==0:
        pass
    else:
        squares={i:i*i for i in xrange(n)}
dict[n]=squares
```

Here is a question: Create a dictionary that maps the first n counting numbers to their squares. Associate the dictionary with the variable squares.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: for starters, you spelled `range` wrong

Answer (score 2):

```
>> squares={i:i*i for i in xrange(10)}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```

Is all you really need. It's called a dictionary comprehension and it's a sugar syntax for a `for loop`.

As for your code, you didn't spell `range` correctly in line 1, or do you have a generator named `raage`. You also shouldn't pass `n` into your first line then reassign `n` to your temp line in the for loop. `for not_n in range(n)` is how you should do it. Also what if you only give `n=0` then `squares` isn't assign when you get out of the `for loop`. Also don't use `dict` as a variable name since it's a keyword in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with your code is that your not really answering the question. The question asks you to find the squares of the first *n* numbers, and map those numbers to the squares. Instead, your code finds the squares for each number from *0* to *n* every loop.

But rather than of writing a normal for-loop, You can greatly simplify your code by using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> def map_nums_to_squares(n):
    return {i: i * i for i in range(n + 1)}

>>> map_nums_to_squares(2)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4}
>>> map_nums_to_squares(5)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25}
>>> map_nums_to_squares(10)
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81, 10: 100}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for that question:

```
squares={}
m=n
t=1
while m!=0:
    squares[m]=m*m
    t+=1
    m-=1
```

I used a different variable than n to keep track of how many times the loop needs to run because they do not want you to change the value of n for some reason.